# How to prevent over-installation of software

Tags: windows, licensing

I have a software product installed on multiple machines at a client's site.  The software accesses a database which is located on a server.

I have given them an MSI so that they can install the software on further machines if required.

How can I programmatically place a limit on the number of machines the software can be installed on?

The software previously placed a value in a HKLM registry key, but Vista and Win 7 doesn't allow the HKLM key to be written to anymore, so how am I meant to monitor installations now?

Comment: How do you know if the software is installed? What if they reimage a hard drive, or uninstall it from a computer or two, or clone a virtual disk with your program on it? Does it just count when the program "phones home" accessing the db on a server? Can you have multiple dbs, some clients using one, some clients using another?  These are the kinds of questions that first come to mind when you speak about the problem of tracking software.

Comment: @JohnK: When the app starts it will check an HKLM registry key for a workstation ID which if not found will be allocated. A list of these workstation IDs is stored on the database.  If the list is already at a defined limit then no further workstation IDs will be allocated.

Comment: @JohnK: but Vista and Win 7 do not allow apps to write to the HKLM registry key, so the current mechanism needs to be re-written, but how?

Answer (score 1):

There are products like Symantec client management suite and server management suite which would let you do the software license management of all your software over the network. See [here](http://www.symantec.com/business/inventory-solution). Although, I'm afraid, they're enterprise products and might cost that way. I've actually worked on developing both of them.

Answer (score 1):

You likely should make your legacy app UAC aware (e.g. [Microsoft instruction for application developers on Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756973.aspx), a [Code Project tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/MakingAppsUACAware.aspx)) and request special privileges for it, to continue to use HKLM or equivalent. Once your program has the proper privileges (e.g. administrator) it should be able to continue functioning in the UAC environment as it did in legacy Windows.

One side effect is a non-administrator would not be able to properly install your program, but this is not unusual in the "new world" of Window Vista, 7, and everything going forward. It looks like the "everybody is an administrator" philosophy is not coming back.

(Note: I use the term "administrator privilege" but mean whatever is the least privilege you will need to get the job done).

Likely it will require a bit of work, when I see caveats like this in quotes:

> Elevation procedures surrounding
>   installers are a bit too complex to go
>   into detail here, however be warned
>   that the requiresAdministrator flag on
>   an MSI package does not actually
>   provide full administrator
>   permissions. This actually behaves
>   slightly differently and runs as a
>   subset of the full privileges unless
>   you use a bootstrapper to gain full
>   elevation. It is rare that installers
>   would require these additional tokens
>   as the installer's administrator
>   permissions are generally sufficient.

The benefit is once you've converted one app, you will have the knowledge and code base to upgrade other programs accordingly.

I'm sure other people will suggest code workarounds which are satisfactory and likely won't use HKLM.